# Displaying all the data in an array when it is a mixture of normal array and nested array

Tags: php, laravel

I got an array that looks like this

```
    $arr = [
        'body' => "",
        'json' => [
            'status' => '1',
            'fields' => [
                'title' => 'Product 1',
                'category' => 'Category 1',
                'description' => 'Test User 12',
            ],
            'token' => 'egrgreGERGREglergjerjgiorj'
        ],
        'status' => 200,
    ];
```

What I would like to do is display all the data. The problem I have is that I get this error

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Here is my code.

My controller

```
    $arr = [
        'body' => "",
        'json' => [
            'status' => '1',
            'fields' => [
                'title' => 'Product 1',
                'category' => 'Category 1',
                'description' => 'Test User 12',
            ],
            'token' => 'egrgreGERGREglergjerjgiorj'
        ],
        'status' => 200,
    ];

    return view('test', ['array' => $arr2]);
```

My blade

```
    @if(isset($arr2))
        @foreach($arr2 as $k => $v)
            {{ $k }} - {{ $v }}
        @endforeach
    @endif
```

Comment: Please post here where you have used `htmlspecialchars` function inside code.

Comment: @NikuNjRathod: Blade template engine use `htmlspecialchars()` when it echo value

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code on your blade file.

```
@if(isset($arr2))
    @foreach($arr2 as $k => $v)
        @if(is_array($v))
            @foreach($v as $Innerk => $Innerv)
                {{ $Innerk }} - {{ $Innerv }}
            @endforeach
        @else
            {{ $k }} - {{ $v }}
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endif
```

It will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you have array inside array that is a multidimensional array. in the first iteration, you are echoing array content, which is happens to be another array. blade `{{ }}` can print string, not array. so you are getting this error

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

you have to check if the value is array or not. then print it.

```
@if (isset($arr2))
    @foreach ($arr2 as $k => $v)
        {{ $k }} - 
        @if (is_array($v)) 
            @foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2)
                @if (is_array($v2)) 
                    @foreach ($v2 as $k3 => $v3)
                        {{ $k3 }} - {{ $v3 }}
                    @endforeach
                @else
                    {{ $v2 }}
                @endif
            @endforeach
        @else
            {{ $v }}
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endif
```

the problem here is if you don't know the depth of your multidimensional array, you have to loop again and again.

Answer (score 0):

You could flatten the array into a single dimension and use dot notation for the keys:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

$flattened = Arr::dot($arr); // $arr is your array

// would give you an array like this
[
 "body" => "",
 "json.status" => "1",
 "json.fields.title" => "Product 1",
 "json.fields.category" => "Category 1",
 "json.fields.description" => "Test User 12",
 "json.token" => "egrgreGERGREglergjerjgiorj",
 "status" => 200,
]
```

Now you can use one loop to list all the keys and values:

```
@foreach ($flattened as $key => $value)
    {{ $key }} - {{ $value }}
@endforeach
```

If you don't want anything but the last segment of the key's name you can display only that part:

```
@foreach ($flattened as $key => $value)
    {{ last(explode('.', $key)) }} - {{ $value }}
@endforeach
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Helpers - Arrays and Objects](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-array-dot) `Arr::dot`

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Helpers - Arrays and Objects](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-last) `last`